# Setting recovery options on windows services

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've recently written a small class to help me change recovery options on a windows service (most of code I found online somewhere).  The code creates a FailureAction for the first, second, and subsequent failures.  Each Failure object contains a type (None, Restart, Reboot, RunCommand), and a Delay (int) in milliseconds.  These objects are packaged inside a struct and passed into ChangeServiceConfig2 (WinAPI P/Invoke).  However, when I actually right-click on a service on the console and go to the Recovery tab, you can only set the delay ("Restart server after" field) once for all failures (first, second and subsequent).  When I set this programmatically, it takes the delay from the first FailureAction and ignores all others.  Does anyone know why this is the case?  Why do we have to pass in a delay value for all FailureAction objects when only the first one gets used?  Am I misunderstanding something?

Also, setting dwResetPeriod/"Reset fail count after" doesn't seem to have any effect.

Code:

```
public class ServiceConfigurator
{
    private const int SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF01FF;
    private const int SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF003F;
    private const int SERVICE_CONFIG_DESCRIPTION = 0x1;
    private const int SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS = 0x2;
    private const int SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = -1;
    private const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS
    {
        public int dwResetPeriod;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string lpRebootMsg;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string lpCommand;
        public int cActions;
        public IntPtr lpsaActions;
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ChangeServiceConfig2")]
    private static extern bool ChangeServiceFailureActions(IntPtr hService, int dwInfoLevel, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS lpInfo);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ChangeServiceConfig2")]
    private static extern bool ChangeServiceDescription(IntPtr hService, int dwInfoLevel, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref SERVICE_DESCRIPTION lpInfo);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetLastError();

    private IntPtr _ServiceHandle;
    public IntPtr ServiceHandle { get { return _ServiceHandle; } }

    public ServiceConfigurator(ServiceController svcController)
    {
        this._ServiceHandle = svcController.ServiceHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
    }

    public void SetRecoveryOptions(FailureAction pFirstFailure, FailureAction pSecondFailure, FailureAction pSubsequentFailures, int pDaysToResetFailureCount = 0)
    {
        int NUM_ACTIONS = 3;
        int[] arrActions = new int[NUM_ACTIONS * 2];
        int index = 0;
        arrActions[index++] = (int)pFirstFailure.Type;
        arrActions[index++] = pFirstFailure.Delay;
        arrActions[index++] = (int)pSecondFailure.Type;
        arrActions[index++] = pSecondFailure.Delay;
        arrActions[index++] = (int)pSubsequentFailures.Type;
        arrActions[index++] = pSubsequentFailures.Delay;

        IntPtr tmpBuff = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(NUM_ACTIONS * 8);

        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(arrActions, 0, tmpBuff, NUM_ACTIONS * 2);
            SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS sfa = new SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS();
            sfa.cActions = 3;
            sfa.dwResetPeriod = pDaysToResetFailureCount;
            sfa.lpCommand = null;
            sfa.lpRebootMsg = null;
            sfa.lpsaActions = new IntPtr(tmpBuff.ToInt32());

            bool success = ChangeServiceFailureActions(_ServiceHandle, SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS, ref sfa);
            if(!success)
            {
                if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                    throw new Exception("Access denied while setting failure actions.");
                else
                    throw new Exception("Unknown error while setting failure actions.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tmpBuff);
            tmpBuff = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Trevor

Comment: To your question on why it only takes only the first I'm assuming that Microsoft hasn't implemented a diff delay for each failure action. It was probably easier to have use one struct type for each failure despite only the first one being used. Also, the recovery tab in the service manager window only has one entry for "Restart Service after:" so it seems like Windows currently only intends to pay attention to the first one. HTH

Comment: @threed, this code is missing definition of FailureAction

Comment: @user626528: I'm afraid I no longer have access to the code (I'm with a different company now).  But as far as I can remember, the `FailureAction` class is essentially what you see in the example code, a class with two properties: `Type` and `Delay`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have discovered that all flavors of win 7 have no ability to restart some services even when their restart upon failure is set to yes.

I ended up writing a service to monitor start and stop status as well as (heuristics derived) responsiveness (eg hung not hung). Would you like that services code posted here?

**Edit: Added the code**

Ok, the following is the service code I referred to. Bear in mind:

- This code is designed to point to "C:\appMon" for logging, and cpu util. threshold values.
- This code is ugly in that it was cranked out while I was slammed with other priorities - as a result, it could be rewritten to handle any number of services, user defined log and cfg paths, etc.
- The service it was written for is the notorious windows spooler (spoolsv.exe).

To install the service, use installutil.exe from MS. Make sure the service runs as a "local system account" or it will not be able to start/stop services.

appMon.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;

namespace appMon
{
    public class appMon : ServiceBase
    {
        public const string serviceName = "appMon";     
        public appMon()
        {
            InitializeComponent();          
        }       
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.ServiceName = serviceName;         
        }       
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // free instantiated object resources not handled by garbage collector
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        public static string getCurrUser()
        {// gets the owner of explorer.exe/UI to determine current logged in user
            String User = String.Empty;
            String Domain = String.Empty;
            String OwnerSID = String.Empty;
            string processname = String.Empty;
            int PID = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0].Id;
            ObjectQuery sq = new ObjectQuery
                ("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessID = '" + PID + "'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sq);            
            foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in searcher.Get())
            {
                string[] o = new String[2];
                oReturn.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])o);
                User = o[0];
                System.IO.StreamWriter sr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\user.txt");
                sr.WriteLine("\\" + o[2] + "\\" + o[1] + "\\" + o[0]);
                return User;
            }
            return User;
        }
        public static int readConfigFile()
        {
            int cputime = 5; // 5 min dflt
            try
            {
                string readcfg;
                readcfg = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\appMon\cpuUtilization.txt");
                cputime = Convert.ToInt16(readcfg);
                return cputime;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                return cputime;  // 5 min dflt
            }
        }
        public static void logEvents(bool spoolerHang, bool appHang, string msg)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter sw;
                sw = File.AppendText(@"c:\appMon\appMonLog.txt");
                sw.WriteLine(@"appMon spoolsv.exe event: " + "," + System.Environment.MachineName + "," + System.DateTime.Now + "," + msg);
                sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Start this service.
        /// </summary> 
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {// upon appMon load, a polling interval is set (in milliseconds 1000 ms = 1 s)
            System.Timers.Timer pollTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            pollTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(pollTimer_Elapsed);
            pollTimer.Interval = 20000; // 20 sec
            pollTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
                if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) // if service is not running...
                {
                    service.Start(); // ...start the service
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        public static void StopService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            try
            {
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
                if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) // if service is running...
                {
                    service.Stop(); //...stop the service
                }
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        public static void delFiles(string path)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // TODO:  !log to file instead!
                    MessageBox.Show("error deleting files: " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        public static void getServiceInfo(string serviceName)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
            ServiceController[] depServices = service.ServicesDependedOn;
            List<string> depServicesList = new List<string>();
            foreach (ServiceController sc in depServices)
            {
                depServicesList.Add(sc.ServicesDependedOn.ToString());
                logEvents(false, false, sc.ServicesDependedOn.ToString());
            }

        }
        void pollTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {// polling interval has elapsed            
            getServiceInfo("spooler");
            ServiceController serviceSpooler = new ServiceController("spooler");
            if (serviceSpooler.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                logEvents(true, false, "Print Spooler is: " + serviceSpooler.Status.ToString());
                serviceSpooler.Refresh();
                serviceSpooler.Start();
                logEvents(true, false, "Print Spooler is: " + serviceSpooler.Status.ToString());
            }            
            int cputime = readConfigFile();
            // get active processes (exe's, including services)
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            // iterate through process list
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                // assign local variable to iterator - cures the foreach "gotcha"
                Process p = theprocess;
                if (p.ProcessName == "spoolsv") // "spoolsv" = windows name for spoolsv.exe aka "spooler"
                {
                    if (p.TotalProcessorTime.Minutes > cputime) // has current spooler thread occupied >= cputime # mins of CPU time? 
                    {
                        logEvents(true, false, "spoolsv.exe CPU time (mins): " + p.TotalProcessorTime.Minutes.ToString());
                        p.Refresh();
                        StopService("spooler", 0);
                        StartService("spooler", 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Stop this service.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @negEntropy: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not open additional answers if you want to add something to you existing answer, or clarify a point. Use edit feature to edit your existing answer. Please refer to this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Answer (score 29):

The sc command provides a great way for automating service management. To call from code just do a `Process.Start("sc", "args")` and redirect the output if you want to get the result.

This one line tells the service to restart twice after waiting 1 min. on failure. After one day goes by it resets the failure count. You can also set it up to run programs, etc. on subsequent failures.

```
sc failure myservice reset= 86400 actions= restart/60000/restart/60000//
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: If you're going to call this from the Installer[] service install handler in C#, you can insert this call into the .Committed event handler which will execute it after the service appears in service manager. Don't put it in the "AfterInstall" event manager, as it this won't work the very first time the service is installed on the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Windows service recovery options using the Windows registry option by taking the binary string value of the recovery options.
If you look in the Windows registry where your service is installed the key FailureActions is used to set the recovery option which has a binary value. [If you check the image it has the binary value I have taken from the Windows registry the path where your service would be installed in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\serviceName`

[image: 1]

Check the below code for setting Windows recovery options programmatically.
You can use the `ManagementClass` for the Windows registry as well.

```cs
string strFailureActionBinary = "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-03-00-00-00-14-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-60-EA-00-00-01-00-00-00-60-EA-00-00-01-00-00-00-60-EA-00-00";
string[] arrFailureActionBinary = strFailureActionBinary.Split(new string[]
{
    "-"
}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var mcReg = new ManagementClass(_managementScopeForRegistry, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), _objectGetOptions);
var inparamsReg = mcReg.GetMethodParameters("SetBinaryValue");
inparamsReg["hDefKey"] = 0x80000002; // HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
inparamsReg["sSubKeyName"] = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\" + serviceName;
inparamsReg["sValueName"] = "FailureActions";
inparamsReg["uValue"] = arrFailureActionBinary.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x, 16)).ToArray(); //its expect value in array
mcReg.InvokeMethod("SetBinaryValue", inparamsReg, null);
```