# Programatically launch Update Driver Wizard for specific device

Tags: c#, device-manager, rundll32

How do you programmatically open the "Update driver" wizard for a specific Device?

I am trying to replicate the Device Manager functionality from a WinForms C# app. So far I was able to replicate everything, including calling the Device Property page, enable/disable device and such.

I can't figure out what does the "Update Driver" context menu invokes, it does open the Update Driver Software Wizard for that selected deviceId but I can't figure out how to call it manually.

pnputil.exe did not do the trick neither, as I need to open the wizard, not specify a driver package directly.

Has anyone been able to replicate this behavior?

Comment: Are you using MMC20 COM application model? If so, can you post the code you have written so far? If that's the tool you're utilizing, it's weird that you can disable a device but not invoke the Update Wizard, those are both Menu actions that can be triggered by the same underlying object (with `[View].ExecuteScopeNodeMenuItem()`)

Comment: No, I am not, for disable/enable device i am using purely P/invoke calls

Comment: And to open the device properties I am using DeviceProperties_RunDLL from devmgr.dll

Comment: Why are you PInvoking, when the MMC [exposes an object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/mmc/mmc-reference) for automation? Or you could also use UIAutomation -- An example of the former here: [How to open the Property dialog of selected objects in Management Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640561/7444103)