# Auto restart windows service

Tags: c#

I am trying to a Window Service in C#, which should be running always. If there is a crash or shutdown, then it should automatically restart. I considered using Service controller class, but the problem is how to handle if both Service Controller & Service go down at same time. 
Is there a watchdog functionality in Windows with which I can register and it takes care of the service start up?

Comment: just an idea : may be windows scheduled task which execute console app in every minute can check the service status and start if not running

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting recovery options on windows services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364700/setting-recovery-options-on-windows-services)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could consider using recovery options of service. It can be set through properties of the service when running services.msc.

Please look [here](http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/using-the-automatic-recovery-features-of-windows-services/) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above recommended pattern, probably it's a good idea to 
Catch the unhandled exception by subscribing to the appdomain.unhandledexception event.
And unload the application domain so that the windows service manager will
initiate the recovery procedure.

```
AppDoamin.currentAppDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHandler);


void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
       Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One recommended pattern here is to set the service start up options to 'Auto' and also, ensure the core functionality of your service is wrapped in a try/catch block.

```
try 
{
 // core code here.
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
 // log it for debugging and swallow so that service doesn't crash.
}
```

this ensures that your service is always running. the code will not crash it, and when the machine reboots etc., the service is auto started.

Comment: Swallowing exceptions is a no-no.

Comment: @fsimonazzi i should have been clearer. the outermost blocks of console apps, windows services etc. need to be guarded against unhandled exceptions.. since the process dies otherwise. and one possible way to guard against such unhandled crashes is to put a try/catch at the outermost level, and log the exception clearly. basically handle the exception. (not swallow it) my above answer meant to explain handling it.. i used the word 'swallow' just because we are not throwing it or letting it bubble up. we are handling it.

Comment: In my experience, this is still a no-no. You're better off just setting the service to auto-restart (See @pepo's answer) and killing the executable. Then you are assured of a clean start. I've spent many an hour debugging issues caused by "handling" and internally-restarting services and in my opinion, it's not worth it.