# How can I automatically catch and restart a crashed process on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

This might be silly. When my process crashes, a **WerFault.exe** has been launched and I can regain control only after I close this window or kill its task.

I'm looking for a simple way of not letting crashed program show this window or any idea for me to catch this crash.

SEH is not useful, by the way. I'm not sure why. The crash also remains when I use SEH.

Thanks!

Now I'm just figuring out how to avoid this **WerFault.exe** windows and sometimes **csrss.exe** window and regain control.

Comment: Not sure whether this is still accurate, but http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/121434 describes how to assign a default debugger.

Comment: @HarryJohnston It's normal that my process crashes. It runs several tests on a static library.

Comment: Have you tried using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`?

Comment: @JimYang: the idea is that a custom debugger could restart the process automatically.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364700/setting-recovery-options-on-windows-services also

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Application Recovery and Restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948909.aspx) API to have Windows Error Reporting (WER) restart and recover your app when it crashes.  Use [`RegisterApplicationRestart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373347.aspx) to register your intent to be restarted.  Use [`RegisterApplicationRecoveryCallback()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373345.aspx) to register your intent to save and recover state data.

Comment: Good find (+1), but not sure that this will work much better for what the OP wants, since it will pop up a "Do you want to restart?" dialog when the application crashes, which is just as obnoxious as "Do you want to send an error report?". Plus, it requires the application running for at least 60 seconds, which may be a lot for a test program.

Comment: It seems not what I want. I still need to manully close the "OOPS I crashed:(" window and regain control.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but this api : `WerAddExcludedApplication` should disable error raporting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513617%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

As for restarting your app, you could create another background process that will start your main process and monitor how it behaves. If it crashes then restart it.

[edit]

unfortunately this api might not work, as suggested in comments to it - to remove this dialog your will have to `FindWindow() and SendMessage(... WM_CLOSE...).`

Comment: Are you suggestting that I should create another thread that runs **FindWindow(..."WerFault.exe"...)** over and over again?..

Comment: Okay I've tried **WerAddExcludedApplication** and instead of a 'large' window, it creates a tiny window :). It's cute but not what I want.

Comment: You could probably do better than FindWindow; Raymond Chen has written a number of articles about UI Automation recently, e.g., http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/17/10500645.aspx