# How to set recovery action for windows service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am looking for a solution about how to set up a recovery action when a service fails programmaticaly in C#. There are 4 options under service | properties | Recovery. Default one is "Take No Action". I would like to set "Restart the Service" by a external program written in C#. I can start/stop the service by program but don't find anyway to set the recovery action ("Restart the Service").

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To run an external program, select the "Run a Program" option and fill in the details:

[image]

Your C# program can restart the service if that is what you would like to happen.

Comment: I am looking for how can I set "Restart the Service" by external program. I can't access the dialog that is shown here.

Comment: Your code can call the [ChangeServiceConfig2 function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx) with the SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS object containing the details in the lpCommand component. C# code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364700/setting-recovery-options-on-windows-services